# django admin: text field as an option list

Tags: django-admin

I want to be able to provide a list of possible values when entering a text field in django admin. I have a legacy database so I can't add a new model and reference that.

Could I provide something like:

```
possible_values = ['one','two',three']
```

to the fieldsets tuple, for a particular field in model handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured this one out with the help of the excellent djangoproject documentation:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

You add a tuple:

```
COUNT_OPTIONS = (
  ('1','one'),
  ('2','two'),
)
```

Then in for a particular model

```
count = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, choices=COUNT_OPTIONS)
```

I knew there had to be an easy way ...